# How to Schedule Method call in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I am try to do multi-threading in Objective C.
What I want to do now is that,
for some instance of objects, 
I want to have to way to call some function 5 seconds later.
How can I do that?

In Coco 2D, it's very easy to do it. They have something called scheduler.
In Objective C, how to do it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use **[performSelector:withObject:afterDelay](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:)**:

For example:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myFunc:) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

Comment: thanks. also of interest:
+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector object:(id)anArgument

Comment: The code above has an error, the : after the selector call is not needed for methods with no arguments. [self performSelector:@selector(myFunc) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what has been said, if you'd like to pass a single argument to myFunc, the call could be modified as follows

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showNote:) withObject:@"S" afterDelay:1.0];
```

and if you need to invoke a method that takes more than 1 argument, you can do that using invocation as shown in the following snippet -

```
SEL selector = @selector(nextPicture:);
NSMethodSignature *signature = [[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[invocation setSelector:selector];

//Set the arguments
[invocation setTarget:self];
NSString* str = [imageNames objectAtIndex:1];
[invocation setArgument:&str atIndex:2];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f invocation:invocation repeats:NO];
```

Comment: Before turning to `NSInvocation` I would recommend using `dispatch_after`. Just start typing it in Xcode and accept the autocompletion, and put your code to be executed after a delay in the block.

Comment: dispatch_after was a great recommendation, and actually something I didn't even know about until now. That is an extremely useful code snippet since it makes it much easier to call methods that take one or more arguments a lot easier (or multiple methods in a row). Basically, a delayed block call is infinitely more useful than limiting to a single selector.