# Run Method everyday at certain time

Tags: objective-c, macos, launchd

I am writing a menu bar application, I need to run a method every day at a certian time. I would like it to run even if the user is not logged in. I know I need to create a helper tool registering it with launchd. Is there a good tutorial on this? I'm not new to programing but I am new to using helper tools and launched. I have been doing some reading and came across SMJob, and I know I can use it to create helper tools just not how to use it. I just need some direction with this.

Comment: Have a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057192/how-to-schedule-method-call-in-objective-c

Comment: @Marco I don't want to have a counter. I don't think that would be very memory friendly, to have a counter going all the time. Also the user would have to be logged in for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html) 
The solution is to create some command line utility, make launchd plist file in the /Library/LaunchDaemons directory (note that it must be owned by root:wheel and have 0644 mode) and load job via command `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/your.plist` (flag -w forces your job to launch at every boot).
 For the running your job periodically set StartInterval or StartCalendarInterval key in your plist (see "Creating Launch Daemons and Agents" -> "Creating a launchd Property List File" -> "Running a Job Periodically" in the guide for the example")

Comment: Can the command line utility run a method in my existing application?

Comment: no, but it can just do the job, for example reading instructions from some file.

Comment: My application needs to also work on Snow Leopard so would SMJobBless be better?

Comment: If you understand how to use it - go ahead, note only that you can't build your code on Snow Leopard: see requirements https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html And one more thing: I don't know about "run even if the user not logged in" with SMJobBless